# How to call a gRPC microservice from client using eureka?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, netflix-eureka, grpc-java

I am new to gRPC and trying to understand how it works. I have created two microservices, user and order using java in spring boot. I have a client service calling these microservices through GET mapping. For example, if I call user service from client using GET(http://localhost:9090/user/username), it'll return the user details. Now I want to implement server registry. I am using eureka for the same. I have registered order and user service on eureka. Now, I want the client to call user through eureka. In rest api I used rest template and provided the user service name to achieve it. In gRPC, there is no such url and we cannot make any GET or POST request. I am not sure how to proceed. Like how rest template is a client for rest api is there any client for gRPC?

Comment: To invoke the grpc call to the grpc server. You need the gRPC service stubs.
You can refer more: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/

Comment: @GnanaJeyam I have used that. First, I created a gRPC microservice and that is working. Now, I want to implement eureka to that.

Comment: Then you need to just plug Eureka client dependency to your gRPC server app.

Comment: @GnanaJeyam do you mean adding the dependency to the pom file?

Comment: Yeah @Renee You need add that dependency to the pom file

Comment: @GnanaJeyam I have added that. I am confused as to how to call a microservice from the client through eureka

Comment: Do you need to call the gRPC server from your service?

Comment: @GnanaJeyam Yes. I want to call user server from client server but through eureka.

Comment: Using eureka you can just pull the dns/ip for the grpc server. But for the grpc client you should utilize the grpc-java

Comment: @Renee Did you figure out this? Can you please post as answer?